# I need help with grub rescue

Tags: boot

I was trying to get rid of Ubuntu 19.04, because I didnt have much of a use for having a dualboot anymore, so i went to windows 10 (The primary of the dualboot) and wiped all drives and reinstalled windows. Even after that, it still showed up the grub bootmenu with ubuntu still on it. So then, I went to partition manager (Windows) and deleted the Ubuntu partition. And after i rebooted, I went into grub rescue with no windows 10 option before it. And I dont have another Linux partition to fix it with. Can someone give me instructions on how to fix it? The only other option that i know of that worked last time this happened was these old windows 7 cds that i used to get windows 7 then reinstalled windows 10 and got rid of grub from the discs.